# Retrieve information from a video

Tags: video, information-retrieval

Is there any tool to retrieve all possible data information from video in backtrack distribution, or there is in general any tool that can do this?

I've already tried with `ffprobe`, `exiftool`, `mediainfo` and others.

Comment: I think you have already answered your own question. You have named 3 tools that can retrieve all possible data information from video using the BackTrack distribution of Linux (first I've heard of it, but I looked it up). If these tools are not retrieving enough data, you need to amend your question to state: 1) What type of files you are working with (I'm guessing QuickTime based on your previous question); and 2) What data -- exactly -- you are hoping to retrieve that the aforementioned tools have been unable to produce (timestamps again?).

Comment: I' ll try to explain. I' ve this file that is MOV, but I get this file from whatsapp so it' s possible that it was another format. I try to find the author and the creation date or whatever useful information. But this tools give me only the data when i download the file on my computer and doesn' t give me the author. So i' m asking if there is some tool that can do better. I read also with hex editor but I cannot retrieve no one useful information. I' m sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I discover that the original file is mp4.

Comment: So you have an MP4 file (which is a type of MOV file, technically), and using a hex editor, you can tell that there is author metadata inside the file. However, you are unable to get any of the above tools to see author field. Do I have all that correct?

Comment: There are numerous ways to store such metadata in a QuickTime or MP4 file. Can you upload a small sample somewhere (even if it's just the 'moov' atom).

Comment: How can I extract the moov atom?